# How to update HTML for AJAX pages in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to extract HTML from a page and repeat this action in a loop after changing the dropdown on the page. Below is a simplified version of my code. The problem is that after changing the dropdown selection, I get the same code for HTML. That is it gets the same old html code when I run  "html = driver.execute_script(...)" in the loop. I've tried several options for "driver.implicitly_wait()" but it didn't help.
I'd appreciate if anyone can help me to find out what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

url = "https://myurl.com/PATH"  #original url
options = [list of dropdown options]   #list of options in the dropdown menu

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#get the first html of the page
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

for option in options:
    #change dropdown selection
    optionSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dropdown-select"))
    optionSelect.select_by_visible_text(option)

    driver.implicitly_wait(10) #wait until page loads

    # get html code after dropdown change
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

    print(html) 

driver.close()
```

Comment: Do you have a URL that can be used to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, my URL only works on my company's intranet. My question is more about the logic of the code. Is this a correct expectation that "html = driver.execute_script(...)" in the loop get the updated html? or I should use another function...

Comment: _ My question is more about the logic of the code. Is this a correct expectation that "html = driver.execute_script(...)" in the loop get the updated html? or I should use another function..._ You'll be able to find a better answer than I can possibly provide in the docs.